# How to troubleshoot td-agent configuration file

Tags: configuration, fluentd

I am learning to use FluentD.  I am trying to use it to send logs to coralogix.  I have installed the td-agent and I got it to work in a basic manner by using tail plugin to tail a logfile and output plugin to write it to another directory.   So I know my install works but I cannot make the http plugin work for sending data to coralogix.  I do not even get the td-agent.service daemon to run and I get no error information in the td-agent logfile.  All I get is the following information from systemctl status:

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-8-39 td-agent]$ sudo systemctl status -l td-agent.service
● td-agent.service - td-agent: Fluentd based data collector for Treasure Data
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/td-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2022-10-03 20:33:54 UTC; 4s ago
Docs: https://docs.treasuredata.com/display/public/PD/About+Treasure+Data%27s+Server-Side+Agent
Process: 11419 ExecStop=/bin/kill -TERM ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 11467 ExecStart=/opt/td-agent/bin/fluentd --log $TD_AGENT_LOG_FILE --daemon /var/run/td-agent/td-agent.pid $TD_AGENT_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 11203 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 03 20:33:54 ip-172-31-8-39.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: td-agent.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 03 20:33:54 ip-172-31-8-39.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start td-agent: Fluentd based data collector for Treasure Data.
Oct 03 20:33:54 ip-172-31-8-39.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit td-agent.service entered failed state.
Oct 03 20:33:54 ip-172-31-8-39.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: td-agent.service failed.
Oct 03 20:33:54 ip-172-31-8-39.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: td-agent.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 03 20:33:54 ip-172-31-8-39.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped td-agent: Fluentd based data collector for Treasure Data.
Oct 03 20:33:54 ip-172-31-8-39.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for td-agent.service
Oct 03 20:33:54 ip-172-31-8-39.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start td-agent: Fluentd based data collector for Treasure Data.
Oct 03 20:33:54 ip-172-31-8-39.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit td-agent.service entered failed state.
Oct 03 20:33:54 ip-172-31-8-39.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: td-agent.service failed.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-8-39 td-agent]$ sudo systemctl status -l td-agent.service

My td-agent.conf file is:

```
  @type tail
  format none
  read_from_head true
  tag coralogix
  path /var/log/td-agent/coralogix/external/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/coralogix/external/logfile.pos
</source>
<match coralogix>
  @type http
  endpoint "https://api.coralogix.com/logs/rest/singles"
  headers {"private_key":15156465465  -Private Key numbers  -928989023c762e}
  retryable_response_codes 503
  error_response_as_unrecoverable false
  <buffer>
    @type memory
    chunk_limit_size 5MB
    compress gzip
    flush_interval 1s
    overflow_action block
    retry_max_times 5
    retry_type periodic
    retry_wait 2
  </buffer>
  <secondary>
    #If any messages fail to send they will be send to STDOUT for debug.
    @type stdout
  </secondary>
</match>
```

Comment: What do you get when you do a dry run? `td-agent --dry-run`

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-172-31-8-39 td-agent]$ sudo td-agent --dry-run
Traceback (most recent call last):
        18: from /sbin/td-agent:15:in `<main>'
        17: from /sbin/td-agent:15:in `load'
  ...
  ...
           1: from /opt/td-agent/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.15.2/lib/fluent/config/literal_parser.rb:279:in `scan_json'
/opt/td-agent/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.15.2/lib/fluent/config/basic_parser.rb:92:in `parse_error!': got incomplete JSON hash configuration at td-agent.conf line 29,9 (Fluent::ConfigParseError)
 28:   </secondary>
 29: </match>

     ---------^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you are missing the  at the top of the configuration. Don't know if its a copy&paste typo or that's the error.

Never the less, here ( https://coralogix.com/docs/fluentd/ ) you can find an example on how to configure fluentd.

Also --dry-run will log more about the start error.
Cheers.

Comment: The missing <source> was a copy-paste typo.     Your solution helped me solve the problem.  The coralogix documentation stated:  Please note that the key should be inserted without quotation marks or apostrophes.     This is incorrect for my case or perhaps I don't understand the doc.    By adding quotes to the key value,  the problem was solved.    Thank you.